# Javascript Function: external hosting erro only

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have the problem:

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token if on my: plugin.js

My plugin.js:

```
function maskIt(w,e,m,r,a){

    if (!e) var e = window.event
    if (e.keyCode) code = e.keyCode;
    else if (e.which) code = e.which;

    var txt  = (!r) ? w.value.replace(/[^\d]+/gi,'') : w.value.replace(/[^\d]+/gi,'').reverse();
    var mask = (!r) ? m : m.reverse();
    var pre  = (a ) ? a.pre : "";
    var pos  = (a ) ? a.pos : "";
    var ret  = "";
    if(code == 9 || code == 8 || txt.length == mask.replace(/[^#]+/g,'').length) return false;

    for(var x=0,y=0, z=mask.length;x<z && y<txt.length;){
        if(mask.charAt(x)!='#'){
            ret += mask.charAt(x); x++;
            } else{
            ret += txt.charAt(y); y++; x++;
        }
    }
    ret = (!r) ? ret : ret.reverse()        
    w.value = pre+ret+pos;
}
```

The error does not happen on the local server, only the external hosting. Why?

Comment: Did you see what the problem is by looking at the file on the server? Does the console point you to the line? You should really use semicolons on all lines, not random ones.

Comment: Tanks. Solved! I added semicolon.

Comment: @Alisson Yes it's important to use semicolons if you are not using `{...}` for your `if`. In this case the the browser is reading all this `window.event if ...` as a single command. That's why you need `if (!e) var e = window.event;`